# image in placeholder with its own background

Tags: html, css, image

I want to insert an image in a placeholder and make it appear on the right. The background of the placeholder is white, the image is also white but I want to add a gray background so it could be visible. Like this: [image]

I thought to add the image as a button but it could't appear just like that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this method for icon background, else use image instead of `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>` which is a Font Awesome icon.

```css
.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding-right: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 36px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #666;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" />
    <span class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a background to your button style

```
background: #ccc url('path/to/your/image') no-repeat center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using a label using `fontawesome` to display the image.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1em .3em;
  background: darkgray;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:after {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search...">
  <label></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with absolute and relative positioning, and FontAwesome.

To use FA, include this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In the `<head>`. The HTML will be as follows:

```
<div class="data-path-container">
  <input class="data-path" placeholder="From where to grab the data">
  <div class="data-path-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
</div>
```

We'll give `.data-path-container` relative positioning, and width. For the example, the width will be: `calc(30vw + 40px)`.

```
.data-path-container {
  width: calc(30vw + 40px);
  position: relative;
}
```

The input doesn't need much styling either; Just height, padding and border / border-radius to give it a nice curved edge.

```
.data-path-input {
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 30vw;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;  
}
```

The `.data-path-icon` will require quite a lot of CSS:

```
.data-path-icon {
    /* background-color, color, height and width */
  width: 30px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
    /* positioning */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 1px;
    /* centering the search icon */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
    /* curved edge and hover effect */
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
.data-path-container {
  width: calc(30vw + 40px);
  position: relative;
}
.data-path-input {
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 30vw;
  padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;  
}
.data-path-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="data-path-container">
  <input class="data-path-input" placeholder="From where to grab the data">
  <div class="data-path-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
</div>
```